# org.camunda.bpm.engine.RuntimeService bean not found after upgrading to java 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, camunda

After I upgraded to java 17 I am getting error in my service:

```java
@Service
public class CallbackHandlerService {

    public static final long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 30;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CallbackHandlerService.class);
    
    private RuntimeService runtimeService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public CallbackHandlerService(RuntimeService runtimeService) {
        this.runtimeService = runtimeService;
    }
```

Error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in org.onap.so.bpmn.core.workflow.service.CallbackHandlerService required a bean of type 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.RuntimeService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.RuntimeService' in your configuration
```

I tried to add `@Autowired(required=true)` but it does not work

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, provide a [MCVE]

Comment: I am using Springboot 3.0.4, java 17 and camunda-bom 7.14.0-ee. The above service was running fine in java 11 but after upgrading it throws error in junit.

Answer (score 1):

You need Camunda 7.20.x to run with Spring Boot 3.1.x.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/version-compatibility/

Today you could use **7.20.0-alpha5**

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/tags

7.20 GA should be available on the second Tuesday of October = Oct 12

Answer (score 0):

"I am using Springboot 3.0.4, java 17 and camunda-bom 7.14.0-ee"

That's the problem. As you can see in the [compatibiliy matrix](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/version-compatibility/), spring boot 3 is NOT supported right now,  Upgrade camunda to 7.19 and downgrade springboot to 2.7.x and it should work.